# Problems with Pattern matching, implementing SplitAt in scala

Tags: list, scala, split, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement the scala splitAt using pattern matching and this is what I am trying to do:

```
def split[T](someIndex:Int,someList:List[T]):(List[T],List[T]) = {
     def splitHelper[T](currentIndex:Int,someList:List[T],headList:List[T]):(List[T],List[T])= {
     (currentIndex,someList) match {
        case (someIndex,x::tail) => (x::headList,tail)
        case (currentIndex,x::y) => splitHelper(currentIndex+1,y,x::headList)
        case _ => (headList,headList)
        }
     }
     splitHelper(0,someList,List[T]())
}
```

The compiler is complaining by saying:

```
<console>:15: error: unreachable code
 case (currentIndex,x::y) => splitHelper(currentIndex+1,y,x::headList)
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here and why I am getting the unreachable code error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `someIndex` and `currentIndex` (constants) in pattern matching.

```
scala> val a = 1
a: Int = 1

scala> 2 match {
     |   case a => println(a)
     | }
2

scala> 2 match {
     |   case `a` => println("a")
     |   case _ => println("Oops")
     | }
Oops
```

[Chapter 15 of Programming in Scala, First Edition.
"Case Classes and Pattern Matching"
by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, and Bill Venners](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html):

> If you need to, you can still use a lowercase name for a pattern
>   constant, using one of two tricks. First, if the constant is a field
>   of some object, you can prefix it with a qualifier. For instance, pi
>   is a variable pattern, but this.pi or obj.pi are constants even though
>   they start with lowercase letters. If that does not work (because pi
>   is a local variable, say), you can alternatively enclose the variable
>   name in back ticks.

Comment: -Thanks for your response but I don't quite understand. Isn't someIndex and currentIndex constants from the compiler's standpoint?

Comment: @sc_ray For scala compiler `SomeIndex` and `\`someIndex\`` are constants in pattern matching, but `someIndex` is a variable pattern. See "Variable or constant?" in [Chapter 15 of Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html)

Comment: This is super-quirky. I learned something new. Thanks for pointing it out. There are other issues with my snippet but the unreachable code issue has been resolved.