# Finding next element in List using pattern matching

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

I'm playing with Scala pattern matching, trying to make a findNext function:

```
findNext(1,List(1,2,3)) == 2
findNext(2,List(1,2,3)) == 3
findNext(3,List(1,2,3)) == 1

def findNext(needle : Int, haystack : List[Int]): Int = {
    haystack match {
       case Nil => /* handle it */
       case needle::Nil => needle
       case front::needle::back => back.head
       case needle::back::Nil => back.head
    }
}
```

I can make it work for only for the trivial case.

Can this be done using pattern matching? I know I can make it work using methods in list, but this is just a toy program.

Answer (score 3):

```
def findNext(needle : Int, haystack : List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec def loop(needle : Int, haystack : List[Int], trueHead: Int): Option[Int] =
    haystack match {
      case Nil => None
      case `needle` :: next :: _ => Some(next)
      case `needle` :: Nil => Some(trueHead)
      case _ :: tail => loop(needle, tail, trueHead)
    }
  haystack match {
    case Nil | _ :: Nil => None
    case _ => loop(needle, haystack, haystack.head)
  }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863176/406435) for back ticks in pattern matching.

Usage:

```
scala> findNext(1,List(1,2,3))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> findNext(2,List(1,2,3))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> findNext(3,List(1,2,3))
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> findNext(4,List(1,2,3))
res3: Option[Int] = None

scala> findNext(1,List(1,1))
res4: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> findNext(1,List(1))
res5: Option[Int] = None

scala> findNext(1,List())
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting @tailrec as this is the more direct and simple way to handle a "next."

Answer (score 2):

Since the needle may not be found, it's best to return an `Option[Int]` here. Using just the pattern matching, you can solve it with:

```
@tailrec def findNext(needle: Int, haystack: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    haystack match {
      case Nil => None
      case front::next::back if front == needle => Some(next)
      case head::tail => findNext(needle, tail)
    }
  }
```

Or even simpler:

```
  @tailrec def findNext(needle: Int, haystack : List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    haystack match {
      case Nil => None
      case head::tail if head == needle => tail.headOption
      case head::tail => findNext(needle, tail)
    }
  }
```

Note that this returns None if no matches were found in the haystack, unlike your example above. The result of the function could then be combined with the default answer, like so:

```
val haystack = List(1,2,3,4)
findNext(4, haystack) getOrElse haystack.head
```

Comment: For `findNext(3,List(1,2,3)) == 1` this returns `Option[Int] = None` where the example shows it returning the head of the `haystack`.

Comment: Added a note about that. I'm not sure if the author intended that behavior.

Comment: @alexwriteshere Yes, the "findNext" action should be circular. This has been enormous help though.

Comment: `findNext(4, List(1)) getOrElse haystack.head == 1`

Answer (score 1):

This circles back to the head of the original `haystack` if the last element is the `needle` with the help of `if` conditionals. The `findNextR` holds the saved value for the case where the last element is the `needle`.

```
def findNext(needle: Int, haystack: List[Int]): Option[Int]  =  {
  @annotation.tailrec def findNextR(needle: Int, haystack: List[Int], savedHead: Int): Option[Int]  =  {
    haystack match{
      case Nil => None
      case head :: tail => if (head == needle && tail.isEmpty) Some(savedHead)
                                   else if (head == needle) Some(tail.head)
                                   else findNextR(needle, tail, savedHead)
    }
  }
 findNextR(needle, haystack, haystack.head)
}

scala> :load findNext.scala
Loading findNext.scala...
findNext: (needle: Int, haystack: List[Int])Option[Int]

scala> findNext(1, List(1,2,3))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> findNext(2, List(1,2,3))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> findNext(3, List(1,2,3))
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```